# How can I  troubleshoot this "object reference not set to an instance of an object, use new" error

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, while-loop

I am using threads to read from a file and process content. I have the following code:

```
Dim line As String = Nothing
Dim result As String = Nothing
Dim solved As Boolean
While strReader.EndOfStream <> True
    SyncLock strReader
        line = strReader.ReadLine()
        result = "ERROR"
    End SyncLock
    solved = False
    While solved = False
        result = Process(line)
        If Not result.Contains("ERROR") Then
            solved = True
        End If
    End While
    //some code
End While
```

and it gives me that error at line: **If Not result.Contains("ERROR") Then**

with labels works fine but I read that they are bad for coding.

**How can I get rid of this error? What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks!

Comment: What is `Process()`?  Show your code for that function, it seems to be returning `Nothing`.  Is it a class?

Comment: yes, you're right, It was defined as Nothing first

Comment: So. Do you still have a problem?

Comment: You should accept JohnFx's answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error pretty much says it all

```
Process(line)
```

Is returning a null value. Fix `Process()` to return a non-null value.

Alternately you could do this

```
If not result is nothing then 
  solved = not result.Contains("ERROR")
End if
```

Comment: thank you, but I think the problem is inside the process function which has another while loop and it is returning everytime the null string instead of looping

Comment: That's exactly what my answer says.